# What are the main differences between Parse 1 and 2 - https://github.com/ParsePlatform?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to upgrade parse v1 to v2
Does anyone know what are the new features and advantages of the new version?

Comment: i assume that you are using parse.com service right ?

Comment: @RanHassid - yes, you are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you may heard parse.com will shut down their service in January 2017. In order to allow parse.com users smooth transition the parse team release their platform as an open source, this open source name is [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) 
parse-server can be deployed on any cloud platform that can run NodeJS (e.g. AWS, Google cloud, Azure, Heroku and more). 
parse-server contains most of the features that were on parse.com and even more. other than the basic features of parse.com in parse-server you can login users with additional 3rd party providers like: (facebook,twitter,digits,gihub,meetup and more and more) also you can use a very cool feature which call [live query](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/parse-server-goes-realtime-with-live-queries/) this service allows you to subscribe to queries and get real time update on them it's very good for real time purposes. other than that now in your cloud code you can use any NodeJS module that you like and because there are millions of node modules out there you have unlimited options.

so since parse-server the parse team started to tag it with v2